# log directory execution in tensorboard

Tags: python, keras, tensorboard

I am working on a `keras` tutorial (Using Anaconda spyder 3.6 environment for TF on windows 10)  for Mnist Convolution nets. to recognize digits, given at : www.blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html

the problem i am facing is to monitor `tensorboard log`

in my code i use,

```
tensorboard=TensorBoard(log_dir="logs/{}".format(time)))
```

I do add the tensorboard in my keras model.fit( ,callbacks=[tensorboard])

this create the logs folder in my anaconda spyder working directory (which i can see).

However the next step is to open a terminal and run :

```
tensorboard --logdir=logs/
```

Q) where or what should be the terminal? i tried console in `spyder` and `anaocnda` prompt but none works. From `spyder` i get errors like `invalid syntax or no operator assigned.`

Please guide me considering a newbie here.

Much appreciated :)

Comment: when you used tensorboard from console are you at the correct path? like where the logs folder is accessible for tensorboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terminal is the console, where you can execute commands. As you have installed anaconda on windows, you can open the anaconda prompt (windows start menu). First make sure to navigate to your project directory. e.g. `cd C:/projects/myProject`

`tensorboard --logdir=logs` should work then. If it says something like "unrecognized command", tensorboard is not installed. In this case type `conda install tensorboard.` Make sure you use the same [virtual environment](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/why-you-need-python-environments-and-how-to-manage-them-with-conda-85f155f4353c) as your project.

Comment: By project directory you mean the working directory of spyder, right?

Comment: I don´t know syper, I am talking about the path of your code

Comment: THanks @ixeption. I had to install tensorboard in my anaconda prompt and it worked.

Comment: However, spyder console is still not working...it gives invalid syntax error